# File.ReadAllLines Issue

Tags: c#, file-io, datagridview, gridcontrol

I do have a .dll file and I'am trying to read the text file which is in it to my GridControl.
The text file is like this (with more rows...):

```
1111    Maximum     SomethingA
1222    Minimum     SomethingB
1333    MediumS     SomethingC
```

My code:

```
char[] chrArray10 = new char[1];
chrArray10[0] = '\t';
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:/Users/PC-Me/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/ClassLibrary1/ClassLibrary1/bin/Debug/MyDLL.dll");

System.Resources.ResourceManager resourcemanager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ClassLibrary1.Properties.Resources", assembly);

string[] strArrays15 = File.ReadAllLines(resourcemanager.GetString("GISS"));

string[] strArrays16 = strArrays15[0].Split(chrArray10);
DataTable dataTable5 = new DataTable();
string[] strArrays17 = strArrays16;
for (int s = 0; s < (int)strArrays17.Length; s++)
{
    string str5 = strArrays17[s];
    dataTable5.Columns.Add(str5, typeof(string), null);
}
for (int t = 1; t < (int)strArrays15.Length; t++)
{
    char[] chrArray11 = new char[1];
    chrArray11[0] = '\t';
    dataTable5.Rows.Add(strArrays15[t].Split(chrArray11));
}
gridControl2.DataSource = dataTable5;

return;
```

PS: I used to read the .txt file just fine using `File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(Enviroment....)`

Comment: What's the issue you're having?

Comment: What's the problem? **Read the error message**.

Comment: What do you think `File.ReadAllLines` does?

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Do you get an error message? 

By the way, give more meaningful names to your variables.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the error . it was in french . 
#Fixed by Reed Copsey answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'am trying to read the text file which is in it

If the text file is loaded into the resources *as a string*, you can't use `File.ReadAllLines`.  Instead, just read the string and split it:

```
string[] strArrays15 = resourcemanager.GetString("GISS").Split('\n');
```